# Where is the Run button in my Python Cloud 9 IDE application?

Tags: python, cloud9-ide

I created a new Python workspace in Cloud 9 IDE.

I was able to run the included hello-world.py without any issues, using the terminal.

As for a Run button as described by all documentation, and referred to as missing or bugged in exactly zero Google search results, there is nothing. I've scoured the entire interface and cannot find this magical Run button anywhere.

I created a node.js workspace and the Run button was there, working perfectly.

Even hello-world.py says "# click the 'Run' button at the top to start this application"

Is this something that only appears if you pay?

[image]

Comment: Is reinstalling an option? I just went through some effort installing C9 (never heard of it before) and it seems to work fine, the button is there and all

Comment: Not sure what you mean by installing. C9IDE is a web application. If you mean just creating a new workspace, then yes I've tried that. I make a new Hosted Python/Django workspace. I double click hello-world.py to open it up. and (though i shouldn't even need to open it to see the button) still there is no Run button anywhere in the app.

Comment: Well the web app on c9.io works fine without any configuration. I installed the version you can download to use in localhost:3131.

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Yeah, me too. But I don't think that should make a difference

Comment: Can you perhaps include a picture of the environment where it's missing the button? I'll have a look at it later

Comment: So could you tell me if this was the sequence of steps for you as well: 1. from your dashboard, click create new workspace, 2. give it name. open&discoverable. python/django. 3. wait for it to finish processing. 4. when it finishes, click "start editing" 5. double click hello-world.py in the list of files on the left. 6. then there's a running figure icon in the horizontal project bar that runs across the pane on the left with the project files in it? because when i arrive at this point, there simply is no run button.

Comment: Yes I inserted a link to the image in my original post. (I can't embed images because my reputation is too low)

Answer (score 0):

You have to run most of everything through the terminal by either putting 
`#!/usr/bin/python` at the top of your code or by calling `$> python programName.py` in the terminal.

Comment: Then why does all the documentation and a comment in the default file itself allude to a Run button. The same Run button that exists in my node.js workspace? What you're saying is basically like there's nothing wrong and to me it seems like a huge bug is afflicting the site. Sigh (3rd edit) also in my question here I stated very clearly that I have already had no trouble running it from the terminal. I'm trying to understand why there is no Run button when everything says there should be.

Answer (score 0):

I found this a little strange so I went and experimented a bit myself.

As you said, a node.js project has a run button in the status bar as it's supposed to have, but a python project does not.

This made me wonder which other languages do or don't have this button. I tried a couple others (C, C++, Ruby) and none of these had a run button either.

I did come across this in [the docs on Running and Debugging](https://docs.c9.io/running_and_debugging_code.html)

> **Note:** Currently, only Javascript/Node.js applications can make use of
>   the debugger. You can also execute Javascript/Node.js, Python, Ruby,
>   and Apache+PHP applications.

I read this before I even began to experiment, but after having created apps for other non Javascript/Node.js projects only to find they did not have a run button either, I think we can assume that by saying this

> only Javascript/Node.js applications can make use of the debugger.

the C9 team *also* meant that currently only only Javascript/Node.js applications can make use of the **run** function. If so, this could and perhaps should have been stated more clearly though.

Also, a little futher below on that same documentation page it says

> Run in debug mode indicates that you want to run the current code
>   through the debugger. Auto show & hide debug tools will reveal (or
>   collapse) the debugging tools panel described below. You can also work
>   with this presentation by going to **View > Panels**, and configuring the
>   debugger there.

So I figured I'd try what would happend if I clicked **View>Panels**, but that option isn't even available, not for JavaScript/Node.js projects either. I'm not sure what's up with that.

Comment: Yeah I read all that in the documentation as well. Yet their test files say to "hit the run button" and it runs fine in their terminal. Thanks for taking the time. Hopefully they implement/fix this in the future

Comment: Well, it works in the test project they provide, just not in a self-made project